# preserve node changed timestamp during term migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I have precisely the problem described in [d6_term_node migration overwrites node changed timestamps](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2754787):

> The d6_node migration preserves the original 'changed' timestamp for nodes on migration. But, then the d6_term_node migration comes along and sets 'changed' to the import time for any nodes with term references.

The bug has been open for 4 years. As a novice, I do not know how to fix the problem.

A workaround is suggested in comment [#28](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2754787#comment-12785707):

> As a possible ugly work-around, add 0.01 to the timestamp (`'changed' += 0.01`) to keep the existing value. Because php will treat these as != but when mysql goes to insert into an integer column in the DB, it will round down and set to the same value.

However I have been unable to find a simple example to crib from that performs this task. Pointers to a tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the following comment #29, it sounds like the comment is referring to do something like `$row->setSourceProperty('changed', $query->execute()->fetchField() +1 0.01);` in the `prepareRow` method of `TermNode` source plugin. You just reach out the commentators in the thread for more specifics.

Comment: @ShawnConn thanks for the pointer. this is still over my head but I'll investigate correct syntax. For now I have worked around the problem by simply commenting out the `$this->value = REQUEST_TIME` assignment in `ChangedItem.php` during the term migration